# How to remove width attribute from th tag using RegExp and .replace() function

Tags: jquery

I have a table

```
<thead id="tag_1985_103">
 <tr id="tag_1983_103">
  <th width="33.33%"  id="tag_1981_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 1 </th>
  <th width="33.63%"  id="tag_1980_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 2 </th>
  <th width="33.65%"  id="tag_1979_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 3 </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
```

I need to remove width attribute from every th tag, the value not unique.
I tried following code, but not working..

```
var strcontent ='<thead id="tag_1985_103">
<tr id="tag_1983_103">
<th width="33.33%"  id="tag_1981_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 1 
</th>
<th width="33.63%"  id="tag_1980_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 2 </th>
<th width="33.65%"  id="tag_1979_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 3 </th>
</tr>
</thead>';
var srch_pattern = new RegExp('<th width="(\d+)" ([^>]+)>', "gi");
var replace_pattern = '<th $1>';
strcontent = strcontent.replace(srch_pattern, replace_pattern);
```

Please suggest me a solution

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the remove `width="value"` you can use `strcontent = $(strcontent).find("th").removeAttr("width").closest("thead")[0].outerHTML;`

We convert it into an object, then remove the width.

**demo**

```js
$("table thead tr th").removeAttr('width');


var strcontent ='<thead id="tag_1985_103"><tr id="tag_1983_103"><th width="33.33"  id="tag_1981_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 1 </th><th width="33.63"  id="tag_1980_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 2 </th><th width="33.65"  id="tag_1979_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 3 </th></tr></thead>';

strcontent = $(strcontent).find("th").removeAttr("width").closest("thead")[0].outerHTML;

console.log(strcontent)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead id="tag_1985_103">
    <tr id="tag_1983_103">
      <th width="33.33" id="tag_1981_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 1
      </th>
      <th width="33.63" id="tag_1980_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 2 </th>
      <th width="33.65" id="tag_1979_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 3 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I have the html content as a string, thats why i forced to use .replace function.

Comment: Thanks.. its working.. Is it possible to do with RegExp and replace function?

Comment: @Ann Your welcome, I know its possible, but i'm not the strongest on RegEx, so that would be up to someone else to show you.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```js
$(function(){
    var html = '<thead id="tag_1985_103">\r\n'+
       '<tr id="tag_1983_103">\r\n'+
            '<th width="33.33" id="tag_1981_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 1 </th>\r\n'+
            '<th width="33.63" id="tag_1980_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 2 </th>\r\n'+
            '<th width="33.65" id="tag_1979_103" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 3 </th>\r\n'+
        '</tr>\r\n'+
    '</thead>\r\n';     
    console.log(html);
    
    var converted = html.replace(/<th\s\width*=.+?=/gi, '<th id=')
    console.log(converted);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have a doubt.. How to replace the first 'th' child or second 'th' using RegExp.